# Any suggestions for an ultra-lightweight spreadsheet-like application?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, ms-office, numbers

Does anyone have a suggestion for an ultra-light spreadsheet application which is very fast and snappy?

I do most of my deep analysis using advanced statistical programs and I manipulate small-to-medium sized text files using an editor like TextWrangler. However, I occasionally want to put small amounts of data, like from a csv file or cutting and pasting data from an HTML table, into a spreadsheet for some **quick** manipulation.

Under Windows I used to just fire up Excel, but the Mac version of excel is painfully sluggish for this task and Numbers or OpenOffice are not much better. Plus it takes forever for Open/Neo-Office to fire up, when all I want to is a very quick task.

Are there any lightweight applications made for this task? No charting functionality, no advanced computational features, just a number grid with very simple calculations. Basically, the TextWrangler/Textastic equivalent of Word/Pages/NeoOffice but for grid data.

Comment: Have a lok at x-tables:  [ http://www.x-tables.eu ]

Comment: I think this might be the answer. I wish it wasn't $55. Sigh. Eh, I guess low volume software still has to price itself like its 1985.

Comment: What about a non-graphical spreadsheet program like [teapot](https://www.syntax-k.de/projekte/teapot/) or [scim](https://github.com/andmarti1424/sc-im)?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if anything will ever beat Excel for Windows XP.

But I think Google Spreadsheets are a close second. Zippy enough without all the graphics and sluggishness of Numbers / Excel for Mac.

Then again, it runs in your browser.

HTH.